# organise .json data to pandas dataframe/excel

Tags: python, json, pandas, web-scraping

I  had some progression in my webscraping stats from https://liiga.fi/tilastot/joukkueet.

edit. Now i found better way. So example -> https://liiga.fi/api/v1/teams/stats/2017/runkosarja/

How i can scrape stats, like wins, made goals, etc from there and create stats table?

Answer (score 0):

Only get this:

```
id  season  ...              cacheUpdateDate buyTicketsUrl
0       1    2022  ...  2021-11-09T16:54:56.243678Z           NaN
1       4    2022  ...  2021-11-09T16:30:45.387198Z           NaN
2       3    2022  ...  2021-11-09T16:57:55.660414Z           NaN
3       2    2022  ...  2021-11-09T17:05:34.763264Z           NaN
4       6    2022  ...  2021-11-09T16:52:37.081451Z           NaN
..    ...     ...  ...                          ...           ...
518  6909    2022  ...  2021-11-09T17:26:48.886193Z           NaN
519  6898    2022  ...  2021-11-09T16:54:08.527658Z           NaN
520  6902    2022  ...  2021-11-09T16:30:00.998782Z           NaN
521  6910    2022  ...  2021-11-09T17:05:19.950635Z           NaN
522  6906    2022  ...  2021-11-09T16:39:19.910866Z           NaN

[523 rows x 11 columns]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You could use Pandas DataFrames as:

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd

url = "https://liiga.fi/api/v1/games?tournament=all&season=2021" 
r = requests.get(url)
r = r.json()

df = pd.DataFrame(r)

print(df)
```

Since you want to reproduce the standings table, you still need to analyse the raw data that you have. To help you analyse the data, you could create separate the `homeTeam` and `awayTeam` columns into separate DataFrames as

```
homeTeam_list = [ homeTeam for homeTeam in df['homeTeam']]
awayTeam_list = [ awayTeam for awayTeam in df['awayTeam']]

df_homeTeam = pd.DataFrame(homeTeam_list)
df_awayTeam = pd.DataFrame(awayTeam_list)

print(df_awayTeam)
```

In this way you can make loops to calculate the scores for each game, who won, the table score and so on.

Comment: I meant standings table, like in that page.

Comment: Oh, if you want to reproduce the standings table with all the data presented on the website, then you need to do some data analysis first. The `.json` file you have only contained raw data so you still need to determine the number of goals, victories and so on for each team. In that case, you could create DataFrames for each game and then analyse the data for the metrics you desire. ( I will add these two DataFrames in my answer)